# Unit Testing email Sign Up Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm just getting stuck into a Firebase project and brushing up on my unit testing skills.

I use a unit test to check that the correct outcome occurs when entering an invalid email/password in sign up. This is fine.

I also want to check that the correct thing happens when I enter valid details. However I do not wish for a new account to be created everytime I run this test, it would just litter up my Firebase database.

Any ideas for a solution? Perhaps, calling a delete user method straight after? This seems a bit OTT though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely forgot about this question and now knowing a lot more about Unit Testing, anyone else who is trying to do this. Don't. Tests are used to test the code that you have writing and not the core functionality of third party libraries. They should have their own tests.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Test Dummy AKA Mock to represent the business logic that is checking the validity and then saving.  How you do that will depend on how you've built your app but if I was to assume that validating details and saving details are two different functions on the same class or different functions on a separate class then...create a subclass in your Unit Test (nested class is fine) that subclasses your ACTUAL class and overrides the relevant save method to do nothing (or maybe register that the method was called which you can then assert in your test.)  This new subclass then needs to be injected as the instance into your calling class: how you do this/how easy it will be will depend upon how you've architected your app.  Hopefully when you instantiate your calling class you can set a property on it with your mock as part of the test set up.

```
class LoginCapture {
   var loginChecker = LoginChecker()
   func validateLogin() {
       // business logic
       loginChecker.isLoginValid()
   }
   func saveUser() {
       // business Logic
       loginChecker.saveNewUser()
   }
}
class LoginChecker {
   func isLoginValid() -> Bool {
       // business logic
   }
   func saveNewUser() {
       // business logic that creates firebase record
   }

class myUnitTest: XCTestCase {
   var sut: LoginCapture?
   class LoginCheckerMock: LoginChecker {
      var saveCalled = false
      override func saveNewUser() {
         saveCalled = true
      }
   }
   func setup() {
      sut = LoginCapture()
      sut.loginChecker = LoginCheckerMock()
   }
   func myTest() {
      //  run your test logic.  You can also assertTrue that saveCalled = true
```

Obviously, that's just an idea.  You might want to search on Test Dummies, Mocks etc and also Dependency Injection.

Comment: So your saying that I don't actually need to test the Firebase method. just that all is valid with the credentials I enter and assume the Firebase method will work? If so, this is what I have done already.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I read that you wanted to AVOID running Firebase updates!    Given that, I think you might be a bit stuck.  If you want to test that the logic works and working logic writes a record then...your test will need to backout the update as part of teardown. Or you mock the Firebase interface to store in-memory and call an assertion that the update ran.  Personally, I wouldn't unit test Firebase itself (or Frameworks etc) but I would test that my calling code was passing in the right data in the right format.  So mocks then, but it sounds like you know what you're doing there.

Comment: Thanks for your help.